# Submit button on my website won't work on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, button, submit

I can't seem to get my submit button to work on a iphone/ipad. It worked before, does anyone know if they have changed their security settings?

Any advice would be great:

```
input type=submit value="Send In" onClick="MM_validateForm('Points','','RinRange1:999');return document.MM_returnValue">
```

Comment: do you have a test page on your site that people could try out?

Comment: Hmmmm, I can't open up "file:///C:/Kibry%20Footy" from your machine's local hard drive behind your NAT router and firewall.

Comment: i have it setup on a setup onn a host under http://www.nohandswd.com

Comment: no worries!  I'm not super expert at web forms, even under iOS... but I'm +1'ing your question and hopefully it will get some attention from other people who know better than I.